# Typescript replace null with undefined type

Tags: typescript, types, mapped-types

The use case is as follows

I have got

```
type A = {
   a: number | undefined
   b: string
}

// I want a helper type that will make so that the result is

type B = {
   a: number| null
   b: string
}
```

```
type A = {
   a: number | null
   b: string
}

// I want a helper type that will make so that the result is

type B = {
   a: number| undefined
   b: string
}
```

How can that be achieved. I have tried to find something online but I'm only getting javascript land stuff.
It should not add `null`, just replace the undefined with null.
And another helper type that is able to do the opposite ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a mapped type to map through all the properties and apply a conditional type that replaces `undefined` with `null`. You will also need to remove optionality from the properties (optionality implies a union with undefined)

```
type ReplaceUndefinedWithNull<T> = T extends undefined? null : T;
type ToNullProps<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]-?: ReplaceUndefinedWithNull<T[P]>
}
```

To flip the types the other way we can create a similar type:

```
type ReplaceNullWithUndefined<T> = T extends null? undefined: T;
type ToUndefinedProps<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: ReplaceNullWithUndefined<T[P]>
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeBYAUFTBDAXFAdgK4C2ARhAE5QA+Uh+AJhAGYCW+ED6mUpeAzsArsA5ugC+6dKEhQAShDAAbLAGMIAVUYt2nAOqtgACwByhJUoA8AFQB8CKNagQAHsAiN+dbWw4MA-ATmSlB41gDc0uDQ1gD2ZhYAChSxYPw29oioGFAA2olQ7FAA1hAgscyOALoAtP54Cspqmj66DAbGCVbW+VW2ElJoMtAAwg5xXcmp6TD9Q9FQAEIO2Ty4QWSUtEQW3Jh8UILC+GJokmhRso0q6l0dRlpMvpwZ485uHgxeO0qB9E9tMKReayOKPHR+KZpV5ZPb5Qr4EplCrVBqKG4QO6GB6tPw2Xpzc6XaAAEXGsXBzwYUPSi1sQA)

Comment: Thanks a lot Titian, I updated the question, to add the final thing, which is basically do the opposite , are you able to make it work as well ?Thank you

Comment: @RenanCidale should this be two separate helper types or one that flips undefined to null and null to undefined in the same type?

Comment: If you can provide both options for learning purposes that would be amazing, but whatever is easiest. :)

Comment: @RenanCidale added the inverse of the type

Comment: maybe you are able to tackle this one ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75545254/create-a-helper-function-that-is-able-to-keep-the-types-passed-in-typescript . Is an extension of the current question basically.