# Create a helper function that is able to keep the types passed in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types, mapped-types

The use case is as follow:

I want to create a function that keeps the types correctly.

Input

```
type A = {a: number|undefined, string: b} | string
type B = {a: number|null, string: b} | string

type FnType = (a: {a: number | null, string: b}) => {a: number | undefined, b: string}
type FnType2 = (a: {a: number | undefined, string: b}) => {a: number | null, b: string}
type FnType3 = (a: {c: string | undefined, string: d: number}) => {a: string | null, d: number}
```

Function implementation

```
const example = (fn) => (value) => {
   if(typeof value === 'string') return value
   return fn(value)
}
```

The function example return type is then able to provide a type where results in the type A, for the case of the `FnType` and type B for the case of the `FnType2` and so on. The detail here is that the only certain thing we know, is that the value could be a `string`, and the `fn` function can be anything

The way to understand this functionality is simply by taking the example function, and making it so that the types as inferred correctly.

So if I'm passing as `fn` a function with signature
`(a: {a: string | undefined}): => { a: string | null }`, then the signature of the `value` would be

```
string | {a: string | undefined}
```

and the signature of the return type of the `example` function would be inferred as

```
{a: string | null} | string
```

If I'm manually doing this,
then I would for a mapper from A -> B do this:, and do the same on the opposite side, since I have to map back from `null` -> `undefined`

```
const mapper = (val: { a: { key1: number | undefined } | string }): { a: { key1: number | null } | string }} => {
   return {
      a: typeof val.a === 'string' ? val.a : 
          {
              key1: val.a.key1 ?? null
          }
      }

}
```

Comment: Could you make the question a bit more clear and add more examples for the different implementations?

Comment: Sure, I'll update the the question.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wo81gw) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think this does it…

```
function example<T, R>(fn: (val: T) => R) {
  return (val: string | T) => {
    if (typeof val === 'string') return val;
    return fn(val);
  };
}
```

Comment: This almost does it, but is not returning the inferred result type from the `fn` passed in.

Comment: I think it does, but jcalz's is even better. Uses the type of the val parameter to narrow the return type.